# Does this open the door for SQL Injection?

Tags: asp-classic, sql-injection

Setting my var:

```
Foo = request("Bar")
```

Building SQL Query:

```
John.Source = "SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.USER where Name = '"&Foo&"' and ID = '1'"
```

I found this in someones project, does this open the door for SQLi ?

Comment: From where are you requesting `Foo`?

Comment: It is if "Bar" is exposed to outer world (obtains its value from user input, some other system etc). E.g. Bar = x'; delete from dbo.USER; commit --

Comment: You should use a parameterized query to your database, much safer

Comment: @Christian it doesn't matter actually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. `request("Bar")` will take parameters off the `Request.QueryString` or the `Request.Form` collection.

This means that you can in theory tag the following onto the querystring:

```
'; delete * from dbo.USER; select * from user where name='
```

Which will give you a query of

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.USER where Name = ''; delete * from dbo.USER; select * from user where name='' and ID = '1'
```

As one of the commenters said, use parameterized queries instead.

If this really isn't an option then be sure to escape values obtained from the Request collection. This link may help: http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2008/04/28/filtering-sql-injection-from-classic-asp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You need to sanitise the value before inserting it into the query like that. Or use parameterised queries, which is a safer option.